# Jpanel call paintcomponent without repaint()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, paintcomponent

I have an application in java that paint some shapes in jpanel , but I found a weird bug (paintcomponent is called so much time ... every second ! ) so I decided to make all the repaint I write in comments ... the problem is the jpanel still repainting I don't really know how this is possible is there a methods in java that call repaint or what ? and write fonction then call it in jpanel is it bad ? and also another thing I didn't extends from jpanel I just write the code directly inside Jpanel declaration

Comment: You probably have incorrect custom painting code. For example you are setting a property of your component which in turn will invoke repaint() to you are creating an infinite loop. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The code I have is so long and take time to be read (because it's a project) I don't really know what to do except call Thread.sleep to reduce CPU usage

Comment: *" is there a methods in java that call repaint or what ?"* Yes, plenty

Comment: My bet is that you are setting bound properties in your `paintComponent` method or bound properties of other components within the container - but that's just a guess..

Comment: Like what @MadProgrammer please

Comment: `setBackground`, `setForeground`...

Comment: Thank you so much @MadProgrammer ! I found a Jscrollpane.updateUI(); it's the cause of all the problem thank you again !

Comment: You should NEVER have a reason to call `updateUI`, it is not meant for painting or revalidation of the basic UI, it's responsible for updating the look and feel.

Comment: yeah I know this lately , I called it because I wanted the jscrollpane to be update (when I move a shape out of panel) but it's useless to call it ! thanks again

Comment: `I wanted the jscrollpane to be update (when I move a shape out of panel)` - then you use `panel.realidate()`.